# python dictionary value is getting printed on a line but not getting printed on another line in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

I am new to django and using python version 3.8

In my index.html, I am trying to display the products and their info using for loop as below:

```
{% for prod in products %}
<footer class="card-footer">
    <span id="atc_prod_{{ prod.product_id }}" class="atc_prod">prod_{{ prod.product_id }}
    <button class="button is-info is-small card-footer-item cart" id="prod_{{ prod.product_id }}">Add to Cart</button>
    </span>
    <a href="/shop/products/{{ prod.product_id }}"><button class="button is-small is-info card-footer-item cart" id="qv{{ prod.product_id }}">Quick View</button></a>
</footer>
{% endfor %}
```

Structure of products list is as below:

```
products = [
    {'id':'1', 'name':'A'},
    {'id':'2', 'name':'B'},
    {'id':'3', 'name':'C'}
]
```

Same `prod.product_id` is getting used in 3 places (span - id, button - id and a - href) but for few products (2 out of 5), id is blank.

Refer screenshot below of HTML:
[image: HTML - inspect element]

I do not know the reason, please suggest.

Also, please let me know if I missed any of the important info.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So based on your list of dictionaries, your keys are `id` and `name` so you need to do `{{ prod.id }}`;

```
{% for prod in products %}
    <footer class="card-footer">
        <span id="atc_prod_{{ prod.id }}" class="atc_prod">prod_{{ prod.id }}
            <button class="button is-info is-small card-footer-item cart" id="prod_{{ prod.id }}">Add to Cart</button>
        </span>
        <a href="/shop/products/{{ prod.id }}"><button class="button is-small is-info card-footer-item cart" id="qv{{ prod.id }}">Quick View</button></a>
    </footer>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: apologies for confusing, list of dictionaries is just an example, In real dictionary key name is product_id